# in gql (appengine), how do i check if an entity exists matching 2 filters before inserting a new one?

Tags: google-app-engine

the 2 filtered fields would actually be a unique index in sql so i want to see if an entity exists based on these 2 fields before inserting a new one.

currently i have:

```
t2get = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Talk2 WHERE ccc = :1 AND ms = :2", c, theDay)
for x in t2get:
    theKey = x[0]
if theKey:
    t2 = Talk2.get(theKey)
else:
    t2 = Talk2()
```

which errors with:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'theKey' referenced before assignment
```

if the entity doens't exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two fields would actually be a unique index, maybe you should instead use them as the key_name.  It will be faster and you can use a transaction, if needed.

```
def txn():
  key_name = "%d.%d." % (c, theDay)
  t2 = Talk2.get_by_key_name(key_name)
  if not t2:
    t2 = Talk2(key_name=key_name)
    t2.put()

db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

Comment: thanks Robert. that is actually how i had it previously but it didn't seem right. would that be an acceptable (as in agreeable) way to structure that table?

Comment: You do not need any additional tables.  The key is the entity's primary key.  By building it using key_name you ensure the entity is unique.  If you will always want to overwrite existing data you not even need to fetch the entity, just build the key like I showed and put the new entity.

Answer (score 0):

d'uh I figured it out. After hours trawling the web, 10 more minutes finds me the answer:

```
t2 = Talk2.all().filter('ccc =', c).filter('ms =', theDay).get()
```

returns the first entity (if any) ready to be edited.

Comment: This works, but it's not transactional - race conditions are possible here. See Robert's answer for the right way to handle this.